# Using python code to set stimuli to certain locations from excel conditions file

Tags: python, psychopy

I am a final year undergraduate doing my dissertation. I am replicating Reagh's (2016) Mnemonic Similarity Task and am struggling with coding for the Spatial Task.

What I want to achieve is all stimuli coded '5' in my excel file to appear on the left hand side of the screen and all stimuli coded '10' to appear on the right. I've built the rest of my study via builderview and have tried multiple ways of coding this but haven't been successful. Sorry if this is a silly question but am very new to this and have watched and read many things to try and help me - any help at all would be appreciated :) I've added a link to a photo of my excel conditions file.
[SpatialStudy.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is1xf.jpg)

Comment: You should add a code you have tried so far and data snippet as text not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in a pandas dataframe, you can use the [pivot method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) with columns='LeftRight' to reorganize the data so there is a column for each unique value within the Left right column.

Answer (score 0):

For reading the file you could use pandas
and for printing a write should do

```
import pandas as pd 
#reads the csv 
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile") 
#gets all of the ones with 5 on the leftright column 
right = df.loc[df['LeftRight'] == 5]
#gets all of the ones with 10 on the leftright column 
left = df.loc[df['LeftRight'] == 10]
# for the prinring part i dont know if you mean on the right of the output page or you want a black screen so this is just for the output page
sys.stdout.write("%-6s %-50s %-25s\n" % (right, left))
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a code component (from the "custom" component panel in the Builder interface). In its "Begin experiment" tab, insert something like this to map your variable's contents to a position on screen:

```
position_map = {5:-200, 10:200}
```

i.e. we have created a dictionary that will return the corresponding horizontal position when fed a value of either `5` or `10`. Note that I've used arbitrary positions of `-200` and `200` pixels. Replace with whatever values make sense for your stimulus and chosen units.

Then in the relevant stimulus component, put something like this in its "position" field, and set that field to update every repeat:

```
(position_map[LeftRight], 0)
```

PS in the future you might find it better to take queries like this to the dedicated support forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org. StackOverflow can be quite fussy about questions that aren't really programming-based.

Comment: Glad to hear it – please click the check mark beside the answer as a guide to others that this was the solution.